# google app engine for java- repeatedly getting timeout error when using java.net- does this mean I have to shift away from gae?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am developing a web application on Google App Engine for Java...
In this web app, I am calling an API which does some computation and returns data to my application in JSON format... The problem is that all the time there is a timeout error.

As per GAE for JAva docs, we cannot explicitly set the timeout to a user desired value when using java.net...Does this mean that I cannot code my application on Google App Engine? Because the particular API call that is giving timeout error repeatedly, is central to the application that I am working on... I just cannot create the application excluding this specific API call (that is giving timeout).

Is there some way to resolve this? Or do I have to shift away from Google App Engine(for this app at least...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [low-level API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/package-summary.html) instead of java.net? Call `setDeadline()` on `FetchOptions`, passing in seconds as a double, or use the equivalent `FetchOption.Builder` method.

Comment: @DaveWSmith - Can you also tell me how to get the response into a String variable- the response as stored in HTTPResponse object? The response can be (for example) a JSON object or(for example) an XML object... I will use appropriate libraries to convert those into Java objects, but I need the text output of my call....Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a backend: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html
This will not timeout.

Comment: @jontro- unfortunately this particular app is a client facing app with an interactive screen- the result of the api call must be shown in the gui of the web app as soon as possible...thanks anyway...

Comment: You can use the channels api for notification when the request has completed